# Challenging Problems Involving Stacks (Data Structures)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

Does anyone know where I can get lots of challenging programming problems that involve the use of stacks? I'll like to challenge myself with super hard problems.

Comment: Why dont you buy/borrow "Data Structures Using C and C++" by langsam/tennenbaum ?

YOu will get sufficient problems for a week, just for stack. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Favorite

1. Convert Prefix expression to Postfix using stack
2. Implement a stack with O(1) for access to max element
3. Implement tower of hanoi without
   recursion. :)

Take any damn recursive program , which is recursive by intuition, and try to implement it iteratively. Every recursive has a iterative solution.
That should keep you busy for a while. :)

BTW,
Why dont you buy/borrow "Data Structures Using C and C++" by langsam/tennenbaum ?

YOu will get sufficient problem for a week. :)

Comment: Isn't it Langsam, Augenstein, and Tenenbaum?

Comment: Im sorry forgot the Augenstein's name. :)

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for *stack data structure problems* turns up lots of interesting stuff. Here are a few interesting ones (from easier to harder, in my judgment):

1. Check for balanced parentheses, braces, and other paired delimiters in text.
2. Write a postfix calculator. (So `1 3 2 4 + * -` should calculate 1 - (3 * (2+4)).)
3. Use stacks to solve the "N queens" problem. (Place N queens on an N x N chess board so that no two queens are on the same row, column, or diagonal.)

Answer (score 0):

Cracking the Coding Interview, Fourth Edition: 150 Programming Interview Questions and Solutions:
[http://www.amazon.com/Cracking-Coding-Interview-Fourth-Programming/dp/145157827X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/145157827X)

Chapter 3 is dedicated to stacks and queues questions. Here is a sample question:

> How would you design a stack which, in addition to push and pop, also has a function min which returns the minimum element? Push, pop and min should all operate in O(1) time.

Comment: I'll check the book but the sample problem isn't really challenging. It's solution is almost obvious - Compare as you push.

Comment: @Obinna, that's well and good for push, but what do you do for pop? O(1), remember!

Comment: @Obinna, frankly most of the programming problems reduce to relatively simple solutions which in hind-sight are obvious. If something has a solution, then it is probably no longer considered "super hard" and its solution is obvious (if you have a solid understanding of the underlying concepts), but if it doesn't have a solution then it will certainly be "super hard" and the likelihood that you'd find it is dismal!

Comment: OK. I now understand. I'll still get the books that you've recommended. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the library and look at textbooks on data structures. They should all be shelved together, so you can always just find the call number for your current textbook and the others will be right nearby.

I'd expect most would have chapters specifically on stacks, with end-of-chapter problems. There will be a lot of overlap, but you should be able to get a good selection of problems of varying difficulty, along with a range of different explanations for standard problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could learn a stack-based language, like Forth, or a stack virtual machine, like MS's CIL VM. Either one will force you to reconsider how you implement anything you write in it to make use of stacks.